# SAS installation asking for 32 bit sid file even if I have selected 64 bit native installation

Tags: sas

I have selected 64 bit installation and my machine is windows 64 bit. But SAS is asking for a 32 bit installation file. Why is this?
[image]

Comment: Talk to SAS tech support. It looks like the installation and license file don't match.